# Spring Java Hibernate managing save() of multiple entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using these technologies to solve this task : Java, Spring, Hibernate
For instance if I have 3 Entities: User, Company, Address

as usually I should create a DaoImpl class and Dao interface:

```
interface Dao{
void saveUser(User user);
void saveCompany(Company company);
void saveAddress(Address address);
}

@Repository
public class DaoImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements Dao{
void SaveUser(User user){
getHibernateTemplate().save(user);
}
void SaveCompany(Company company){
getHibernateTemplate().save(company);
}
.
.
.

}
```

and here we go for every save() it should have its own method SaveCompany(), SaveUser(), SaveAddress()....

but what if we have hundreds of them is it convenient to be writing a method for everyone of them ?

can we just write such method instead ?

```
void save(Object obj){
getHibernateTemplate().save(obj);
}
```

Comment: I would create a generic `save` method for your entities that behind the scenes calls `getHibernateTemplate().save(obj)` and custom `save` methods in service layer only if there should be a business rule to accomplish before or after saving the entity.

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the pattern described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/251166/The-Generic-DAO-pattern-in-Java-with-Spring-and) Generic Dao Pattern.

The foundation of using a Generic DAO is the CRUD operations that you can perform on each entity.

Comment: Yes Thanks, and sorry for taking time before confirming your answer

Comment: @user3135757 Don't worry it was a pleasure to help you :)